# How do I sell products in my App and avoid in-app purchasing

Tags: iphone

My iPad app needs to sell products however I do not want to use Apple's payment system.  The guides from Apple are very explicit and also don't provide detail.

Is there any place I find out what the rules are and how I can get around it.

e.g. Do I have to load a webpage or can I simply call a webservice for payment etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been detailed MANY times on this site:

- if you are selling products to be used WITHIN THE APP then you HAVE TO USE IAP. This isn't negotiable, apple will just plain reject your app.
- if you are selling products to be used OUTSIDE YOU APP (eg: a nice pair of cashmere gloves) then YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED to use IAP.

How you implement the payment method is completely up to you. You can either use a webview (if thats easier) or you can write your own custom classes to do communicate directly with the payment gateway. Lastly (probably the better option) you could write a hybrid of the two and have a web service that your app communicates with.

> The guides from Apple are very explicit and also don't provide detail.

This seemingly paradoxical statement bears some truth. The guides from apple **are** very expicit. There is a 7 page document on the developer resource which (part of) details in *extensive* clarity the allowed methods of payment and purchasing within your application. Please go and find it - it will really help you. Its called "App Store Review Guidelines - App store resource center". If you really need the url it is https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html